# ios and android sandboxing differences

Tags: android, ios

I have recently started working on android. I understand that each app runs as a separate "user" on android. I rooted my device and when I check the file system using adb for each app, each app has a different user name and group, effectively restricting other apps, and anyone connecting a non-rooted device to pc for moving files in/out of the app sandbox.

What is the equivalent on iOS ? Do ios apps also have different user/group for each app ? If i connect my iphone to mac and use ifunbox, can i move files around within a particular app itself, if not between apps. Does the device have to be jaibroken for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to rooting your device on Android is to Jailbreak your device on iOS. If you were to use iFunbox, just recently, (sadly) they were caught by Apple and were forced to only be able to move around files in Apps with a jailbreak. Although, with a Jailbreak, you can download (as I have figured out in my past experiences) almost 6x as many apps on Cydia (Jailbreak) as you can on root. There is a certain App you can install (paid but free if you have a crack) called iFile, that lets you search through and change the files inside any app. Even though it's complicated and requires skill to edit things, there are tutorials.

But to answer your questions, Jail breaking is the equivalence and you don't need to give any apps root accessibility because it gives it that automatically. Yes, you can, but I would just recommend using iFile. And finally, Yes, iFunbox does now require a Jailbreak. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

My theory for iOS apps is that they have only 1 user but different groups. there are default apps installed on the system like `Newsstand`, `Safari`, etc. that cannot be removed.